# Convert RGB8888 to YUV420 with ColorMatrix.setRGB2YUV()

Tags: java, android, javacv, yuv, colormatrix

I'm trying to find a faster way of converting RGB to YUV using the Android SDK as the standard pixel for pixel methods are pretty slow in Java. ColorMatrices seem to be pretty efficient and I see there's a setRGB2YUV() method but I can't find any examples and the documentation simply says "Set the matrix to convert RGB to YUV" which is completely useless as usual.

Here's part of my initialization code, which is a little compicated slightly with arrays due to multithreading:

```
cacheBitmaps = new Bitmap[NumberOfThreads];
cacheCanvas = new Canvas[NumberOfThreads];
mRGB2YUV = new ColorMatrix();   
cmfRGB2YUV = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(mRGB2YUV);
pRGB2YUV = new Paint();
pRGB2YUV.setColorFilter(cmfRGB2YUV);
for (int m=0; m< NumberOfThreads; m++) {
   cacheBitmaps[m] = Bitmap.createBitmap(widthX,heightY, Config.ARGB_8888);
   cacheCanvas[m] = new Canvas(cacheBitmaps[m]);
}
```

Later I use this to paint an RGB to a canvas with the specified paint:

```
cacheCanvas[n].drawBitmap(fb.frames[n].getAndroidBitmap(),0,0, pRGB2YUV);
```

I've also experimented using a standard matrix that shouldn't apply any changes to the RGB values like this:

```
float[] matrix = { 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, //red
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, //green
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, //blue
0, 0, 0, 0, 1 //alpha
};
mRGB2YUV.set(matrix);
```

Whatever I do I either get black, green or distorted frames in my output video (using JavaCV with FFMPEG and specifying AV_PIX_FMT_NV21 as a color format after copying the final bitmap to an IplImage).

Anyone know how to use this and if it's even possible or does what it says it does?

Comment: Question is a bit old, but got me curious: are you sure matrix is supposed to be 5x4?

Comment: @Sinisa [***ColorMatrixColorFilter:*** *A color filter that transforms colors through a 4x5 color matrix.*](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ColorMatrixColorFilter)